Color properties values for .primary, .secondary, .tertiary styles in SwiftUI?
I'm 'translating' a SwiftUI app to Android Compose, my color scheme so far is based on the predefined styles in the former, such as .primary, .secondary, etc... which looks good enough but now I can't find proper documentation of which specific colors they apply in order to use the same on Android (tried with a color picker but I'm guessing there's some transparency applied).
Is this documented somewhere?
